# How can I run a reset script upon a fatal error in react-native (expo)?

Tags: react-native, error-handling, expo

I want to run a custom reset script for when my app runs into a fatal error.

I need a way to catch a javascript error before it becomes a native error and I need a way to properly call a reset script.

I have tried using `react-native-exception-handler` but it cannot run functions inherited from props. This is a problem because my app uses redux.

I made this component `<ErrorHandler />` render in the top-level `<App />` component so that it calls `setJSExceptionHandler` when any error occurs.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux'
import { View } from 'react-native'

import { setJSExceptionHandler } from 'react-native-exception-handler';
setJSExceptionHandler((error, isFatal) => {
  Actions.errorHandlePage({});
});

class ErrorHandler extends Component {
  render(){
    return <View />
  }
}

export default ErrorHandler;
```

I wanted the app to open this page where it resets everything and lets the user know elegantly, but the error page appears no matter what I put in the `setJSExceptionHandler` function.

Any advice, or components I can use?

Comment: You must eject the Expo to use this module.

Comment: I'm able to make `setJSExceptionHandler` trigger an alert, but I cannot execute an action which updates redux state before it becomes a native exception. That is because the function must be called globally. How will ejecting from expo change this?

Comment: The module is basically designed to download and use packages to Android folders and iOS folders. If you do not eject the Expo, you cannot execute it.